# Derive multiple PDAs for one Public Key with a UUID

Tags: rust, solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-cli

I am trying to derive multiple PDAs with a generated seed and get the error shown in the screenshot. If i don't use the uuid and only the seed and the public key for the PDA it works fine.

[create_planet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQc1a.png)

[planet_struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38vSk.png)

[rpc_call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnCl3.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLymP.png)

Comment: [Do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your lib.rs in the planet struct the seeds are not in the correct format

it should be like this
`seeds=[b"planet",payer.key.as_ref(),&[uuid as u8]]`

and in your rpc call file

```
[anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("planet"),
          wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
          new anchor.BN(80).toArrayLike(Buffer)]
```

Comment: I saw you commenting this on this post. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807112/how-to-derive-pdas-with-multiple-seeds-in-anchor-rust)
I tried it and i get the same error.

Comment: i have tried it in playground check it out https://beta.solpg.io/628cc3fd0e6ab1eb92d947f2

Comment: wow thank you very much. I will try it this way.